# How can I inspect the value of the control argument in the following JQuery .bind() ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, debugging

How can I inspect the value of 'combo' in the following JQuery that's within an .ascx control on an .aspx page?  I've been using the IE JavaScript debugger (which is usually the most capable of the various built-in browser debuggers).  I've been unable, though, to catch the variable when it's in scope, despite having tried setting a breakpoint on different lines of this code:

```
    function SetSexyCombo() {
        $("#myHTMLcontrolId").bind('valueCommit', function (e, combo) {
            var activeCombo = combo;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're having trouble breaking exactly where you need to, the trick I usually use is to place a [`debugger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0bwt76sk%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) statement in the function, like this:

```
function SetSexyCombo() {
    $("#myHTMLcontrolId").bind('valueCommit', function (e, combo) {
        debugger;
        var activeCombo = combo;
    });
}
```

This is basically like a break point (or [`Debugger.Break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) in .NET). It will cause your JavaScript debugger to stop here and allow you to inspect the variables in scope at the moment the statement is executed.

Comment: This doesn't work in the IE JavaScript debugger for my own case, although the MSft documentation says it should http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0bwt76sk(v=vs.94).aspx.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow It works for me. Perhaps you aren't running in debug mode? Open the developer tools (`F12`), select the *Script* tab, and click *start debugging*.

Comment: It look like in my case there's an error that's somehow throwing the debugger out - possibly the control being bound to isn't reporting a valid control.  I'll award you the answer, thanks